# Generating download link for youtube video with PHP but filename always saving as videoplayback.mp4

Tags: youtube, youtube-data-api

I'm tyrying to create a youtube video downloader script for education purpose. Everything is working fine and link generating but the problem is. it is alway's saving the video as **videoplayback.mp4**  , But i want to save video as the title of youtube video. How can i do that any idea or knowledge will you share with me please ? Thanks in Advance :)

**Currently this kind of link generating with my script:**

```
https://r5---sn-ax8xaj5ggpxg-q5je.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?ipbits=0&signature=962BE0E0565BE4A1C47228B9915BCB8F1CFEB960.9F6BB2DB759AEA92819A21B1D7169934E2029F12&key=yt6&itag=18&ratebypass=yes&expire=1493475511&dur=866.382&pl=24&gir=yes&pcm2=yes&sparams=clen,dur,ei,gir,id,initcwndbps,ip,ipbits,itag,lmt,mime,mm,mn,ms,mv,pcm2,pl,ratebypass,requiressl,source,upn,expire&beids=[9466594]&ip=103.250.70.10&lmt=1404765005406941&upn=3jfn7T_trrk&id=o-AIgDAd5Kx005dV22eO8I0kxdhqnMlelHM82MUR6361GG&ei=V0wEWdomgd6jA_7BiQg&initcwndbps=1491250&mn=sn-ax8xaj5ggpxg-q5je&mm=31&requiressl=yes&clen=17929313&mime=video/mp4&source=youtube&ms=au&mv=m&mt=1493453844
```

I'm adding title with this but it's not downloading video with the title

Comment: This question is not about PHP. You generate a link, that link is being clicked on, and everything else (including the filename) is determined by the target of that link, Google in this case.

Comment: Well I did googling. But there isn't any good thing to follow so i'm here.

Comment: I just Stacked on it :(

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: It's been a long. I believe the script for downloading videos doesn't work now.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using PHP to do all your work, then you can rename the file.
You should have the api request info for the video, such as name, id and such. So save the name in a variable and use it to rename the video.

Some basic info [HERE](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php) to start from.
But you can find plenty of examples around renaming on Stackoverflow

Comment: I have the download link but not the specific download address like youtube.com/file_name.mp4   when the URL will use to download then it will redirect and get the filename. So in this case this one not gonna work i think. Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: How are you grabbing the video then? you must have info on the video! So you must have the name or id. Without the id, how do you locate the correct video?

Comment: I got everything. id, title, download link, everything except the title i can't using as filename :(

Comment: If you have the name in php, then you can change the default name to the name that you have in php. The link I gave will give you the basics. For more, do a search on file renaming in php. It is a simple task if you have all the info in your script.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion :)

Answer (score 0):

You may user `title` tag at last of the your url. simply like:

```
https://r1---sn-npoe7ne6.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?c=xxxxxx&title=THIS+ONE+THING+COMPLETES+YOUR+ENTIRE+SALAH
```

Example: `https://r1---sn-npoe7ne6.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?c=WEB&ei=PbcrXNPYN8j8DbS3g6gJ&signature=7158A95D1D19CE23E5927C5BA269FB93416BE9C3.3013C04B8A60583BE3976207ECC46104DA6231C5&ratebypass=yes&dur=78.135&itag=22&lmt=1546275183213302&key=cms1&expire=1546390430&beids=9466587&sparams=dur,ei,expire,id,ip,ipbits,itag,lmt,mime,mip,mm,mn,ms,mv,pl,ratebypass,requiressl,source&ipbits=0&pl=24&mime=video/mp4&id=o-APHRf9RA8ZFNEcdOCNFsj9WVumGp7BSSD5X3KXyvg0yF&source=youtube&txp=5432432&requiressl=yes&ip=107.178.194.200&fvip=1&extension=mp4&mip=119.30.38.95&redirect_counter=1&cm2rm=sn-bg5hxxo2ivox-q5jz7e&fexp=9466587,23763603&req_id=1d7d8e10b833a3ee&cms_redirect=yes&mm=29&mn=sn-npoe7ne6&ms=rdu&mt=1546368708&mv=m&title=THIS+ONE+THING+COMPLETES+YOUR+ENTIRE+SALAH`

Now video will save with

> THIS ONE THING COMPLETES YOUR ENTIRE SALAH.mp4

I think it will help you.